# Group by data to get count between the datetime range

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Let's say I've a table like below

```
start_time           end_time             user_name
2019-01-01 00:00:05  2019-01-01 00:05:05  user1
2019-01-01 00:01:35  2019-01-01 00:06:05  user2
2019-01-01 00:02:05  2019-01-01 00:07:05  user3
2019-01-01 00:03:05  2019-01-01 00:08:05  user1
2019-01-01 00:04:05  2019-01-01 00:09:05  user2
```

My objective is find out how many users were logged in for a **MINUTE**. Say like below

```
time                  active no of users
2019-01-01 00:00:00   1
2019-01-01 00:01:00   2
2019-01-01 00:02:00   3
2019-01-01 00:03:00   3
2019-01-01 00:04:00   3
```

Now I first tried to round of time for a new column `dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, dateadd(s, 30, start_time)), 0)`. So, I will receive like above table `time` column

Next I tried to find the count for rounded datetime like below

```
SELECT
dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, dateadd(s, 30, start_time)), 0) as RoundedDateTime,
(
    SELECT  count(distinct(user_name)) 
    FROM entrytable sh
    WHERE (sh.end_time > dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, dateadd(s, 30, t.start_time)), 0) 
    and sh.start_time <= dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, dateadd(s, 30, t.start_time)), 0))        
) as usercounter
FROM entrytable t
```

But, above SQL query is running for longer time and goes to not responding mode.

I could not fix the issue. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _ logged in for a MINUTE_? Is it OK to assume that you want the count of active users at a given moment?

Comment: @SalmanA yes right

Comment: Why did you remove the `sql-server` tag? Your query is clearly for SQL Server, not standard SQL

Comment: I've done it from mobile app and didn't see it. Thanks for informing

Answer (score 1):

The most trivial solution is this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (start_time datetime, end_time datetime, user_name varchar(10));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2019-01-01 00:00:05', '2019-01-01 00:05:05', 'user1'),
('2019-01-01 00:01:35', '2019-01-01 00:06:05', 'user2'),
('2019-01-01 00:02:05', '2019-01-01 00:07:05', 'user3'),
('2019-01-01 00:03:05', '2019-01-01 00:08:05', 'user1'),
('2019-01-01 00:04:05', '2019-01-01 00:09:05', 'user2');

SELECT dt AS date_time, SUM(SUM(val)) OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS active_count
FROM (
    SELECT start_time, +1 FROM @t UNION ALL
    SELECT end_time,   -1 FROM @t
) cte1(dt, val)
GROUP BY dt
```

This will give you the number of active users whenever there was a change (someone logged in or logged out). Result:

```
| date_time               | active_count |
|-------------------------|--------------|
| 2019-01-01 00:00:05.000 | 1            |
| 2019-01-01 00:01:35.000 | 2            |
| 2019-01-01 00:02:05.000 | 3            |
| 2019-01-01 00:03:05.000 | 4            |
| 2019-01-01 00:04:05.000 | 5            |
| 2019-01-01 00:05:05.000 | 4            |
| 2019-01-01 00:06:05.000 | 3            |
| 2019-01-01 00:07:05.000 | 2            |
| 2019-01-01 00:08:05.000 | 1            |
| 2019-01-01 00:09:05.000 | 0            |
```

Be advised that the result does not contain the "in-between" dates.

Comment: Since I run this sql query on Quality Center, CTE is not allowed. Can you please help me with different approach? Appreciate for taking time to answer the question

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: I ran the query and receiving count in -ve. Also a blank value at the top of the row. Quick question - where are we referring user details in the query?

Comment: There could be rows where logout time is earlier than login time (select * from t where end_time < start_time).

Comment: How can that be? may be if user logged in again, that's possible

Comment: +50 Thanks for your revised comment. I ignored the records that are incorrect like you highlighted. Now getting count seems to be right. Will cross verify with actual data. Thanks for your time. Accepting yours as answer!

Comment: since user access for multiple project, distinct user should be taken in the resultset at a given time (he could do simultaneous login). but, output considers redundant user as new user and count is +1 each time. May I know how to get distinct user?

Comment: Include project id column the UNION ALL part and also include it inside GROUP BY and OVER (PARTITION BY...)

Answer (score 0):

**This question was originally tagged for SQL Server 2012**, so this answer is for SQL Server.

One method is to generate a list of minutes and then:

```
with minutes as (
      select cast('2019-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime) as mm
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 1, minute)
      from cte
      where mm < '2019-01-01 00:00:05'
     )
select m.*,
       (select count(*)
        from entrytable et
        where et.start_time <= m.mm and
              et.end_time > m.mm
       ) as num_actives
from minutes m;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I run query on HP Quality center and it does not allow CTE. Can you please help me with different approach? + user can do simultaneous login. so, same user can be found multiple times at a give time. How to take distinct user details to find active user count at a given time?

Comment: @KarthickRaju . . . I don't understand.  The question is tagged SQL Server 2012, and that database certainly does support CTEs and recursive CTEs.

Comment: Removed the tag. Thanks!